# Closing the lid create an error with the wireless icon

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, icons, laptop

Since updating to 16.04, I encounter a problem where the wifi symbol would become an up and a down arrow. The problem arises when I close the lid, but sometimes it does not matter whether I close the lid or not. I believe this is most likely a bug. Due to this bugs, I cannot connect to other networks from the icon; I have to go into the network settings to connect.

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7265
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 59
   serial: 60:57:18:9b:bb:53
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.1.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:50 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
```

This is the image of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqTcQ.jpg

Comment: Same problem here (Lenovo Z51-70, kernel 4.4.0). Which kernel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service` fixes the problem for me until the next time my computer goes into sleep mode.